# Leaks instrument

Tags: ios, instruments

if I see something in the Leaks instrument, under Leaks section -
as I have highlighted in red in the image, this **already** means
there is a memory leak right?

[image]

Comment: Yes. Also check here for more details on how to use instruments if you already haven't read it :)
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have memory leak in your code and red vertical line in leak, shows the same.
"**Leaked object**" is hierarchy will show the object hierarchy where and how the leak occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This lin show you, that your leak was creat in touchesBegan:withEvent, which called for TiuchDrawView class.